# Jquery File Upload for Swig template engine (NodeJs)

Tags: jquery, node.js, file-upload

I really need to implement Jquery File Upload basic plus.
(demo : https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

I have a routing mechanism to manage file upload like below

```js
app.post("/uploadvideo", functions.uploadVideo);
```

I set the url to /upload video in code below

```js
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = /uploadvideo,    //
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
```

The problem is, it never reaches function.uploadVideo.
I suspect I wrote the url wrong, but I dont know what I should put in there that can make my NodeJs + ExpressJs + Swig + Jquery Upload File can work in uploading file.

Ps: I need to upload mp4 and mp3 files that could be heavy for server (if this is the reason).

Thank you

Comment: try making the url a string.

Comment: @zola what do you mean by a string? Do I have to write it "/uploadvideo" ?

Comment: exactly, currently it looks to me like it's a syntax error, you can use your browsers developer tools or firebug in firefox to see what errors are occuring in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps